# Variable from .width

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, width

I am a total newbie to JavaScript and jQuery, and need some help. Also I apologise if it's easy and Im just not seeing it!

Basically, I'm trying to find the size of an image after it has loaded, so I can use this information to adjust the width of a div.

This is the code currently:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<img id="Img1" src="01.jpg" style="height: 50%; width: 50%;" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(Img1).load(function() {
       alert($(this).width());
    });
});
</script>
```

Which creates a prompt box with the correct width! But I cant seem to find a way to reuse this information or declare a variable from it!

Please can anyone help me? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Try `alert( $(this).attr("width") );` Assuming of course that `this` is a reference to the `img` tag.

Comment: I'm surprised you're getting the correct width with a badly-formed selector. There's no "Img1" element (`<Img1>foo</Img1>`). You can certainly pop the results into a variable once the selector is sorted out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Img1` is the id of `img` element use it as id to select it. To store the value of width you can declare a variable and store in it. And then use the variable wherever required.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgWidth;
    //Selecting image using id selector
    $("#Img1").load(function() {
       imgWidth = $(this).width();
    });
});
```

You should learn at various selectors that `jQuery` offers you to use based on your markup structure. Take a look at this link http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Note: If you want to use this variable across the page then you should define it in the outer or global scope.

Comment: I also figured it was a badly formed selector. Sometimes the problem with a broken appliance is simply that it's not plugged in. ;-)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer this makes more sense to me but it doesn't seem to be quite working. I've taken the Var imgWidth outside of the function then tried to use a doc.write after the function but it outputs 'undefined' any clue as to why?? Thanks either way though!

Comment: Thanks for all your help mate but I found a way to get round it for my specific need. I couldn't seen to find a way to use the variable on a global scope so I made the second function (which added the two widths together) then called upon it within where the alert is. Not sure it that makes sense but still major thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var width; // global/parent-scope variable to hold width
    $(Img1).load(function() {
       width = $(this).width(); // width is now stored in global
    });
});
```

Otherwise your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered setting the DIV width to **auto**? If you do this you will not have to even worry about knowing what the width is.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
var imgWidth;
 $(Img1).load(function() {
   imgWidth = $(this).width();
   alert(imgWidth);
});
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b6LSw/) example. The variable imgWidth would have the width of the image which you could use later.

Comment: This works for the alert but when I try to use a doc.write later it just gives me 'undefined' :( any idea what Im doing wrong?? Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'd need to see how you're using it.